# help with SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following diagram:

[image]

Right now I have queries to find out how much each member has donated and also listing those donations in a list for each member.  Now I want to query the donations table to get the results divided up by each organization.

Something like:

[image]

Can someone please help me with this SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT
    MemberId,
    OrganizationId,
    SUM(Amount) AS `Amount Donated to Organization`,
    COUNT(Amount) AS `Number of Donations`
FROM
    Donations
GROUP BY
    MemberId,
    OrganizationId
;
```